# Pycharm debug console won't autocomplete

Tags: debugging, pycharm

After updating to 2017.2.2, when entering debug console, there is no method autocomplete.

[image]

```
>>> [x for x in dir(datetime) if not x.startswith("__")] 
['MAXYEAR', 'MINYEAR', '_divide_and_round', 'date', 'datetime', 'datetime_CAPI', 'time', 'timedelta', 'timezone', 'tzinfo']
```

Is there way to fix method autocomplete?

**Solution:**

[This](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-25816) is solved after updating to **PyCharm 2017.2.3**

Comment: For the record, I've tried this on 2017.2.2 and 2017.2.3 (The EAPs) and I  didn't have an issue. Under `File > Settings > Tools > Terminal` I have everything checked. Do you have this issue when you are coding as well, or only in the terminal?

Comment: Only in pycharm  debug console.